# Atualizar somente o PHP do easyphp

Tags: php, easyphp

Galera,
Aqui no meu trabalho o PHP está instalado via easyphp. Eu preciso rodar algumas funções que só existe no PHP 5.3 ou superior.

E a versão que está Atualmente é a 5.2.10

Tem como eu atualizar o easyphp ou somente o php? Tenho medo de atualizar tudo e perder os bancos.

Obrigado pela ajuda pessoal.

Answer (score -1):

O Easyphp é um WAMP, que visa facilitar a instalação de serviços baseados em PHP (Banco de Dados, servidor, linguagem php, etc). Você pode baixar uma versão atual do Easyphp e atualizar só a versão do PHP, ou atualiza-la manualmente sem mexer no banco de dados.

Porém, como em toda atualização, é recomendável fazer o backup dos arquivos mais importantes e do banco de dados, para o caso de alguma falha. Se a empresa não possui uma rotina de backup de banco de dados, a atualização de versões será apenas mais um componente que poderá gerar perda de dados sensíveis.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda